# Array a[i] prints in descending order, but my logic is for ascending order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Can you please tell me why I am always getting array `a[i]` in descending order only? Please help.

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)  
{    
    for (j=0;j<10;j++)
    {   
       if(a[i]>=a[j])
       { 
          temp=a[i];
          a[i]=a[j];
          a[j]=temp;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: **1.** Don't panic. **2.** Use debugger. **3.** Panic.

Comment: Did you even *try* to change comparison?

Comment: "but my logic is for ascending order" - no, it isn't.

Comment: This happens when you copy someones code without understanding how it works.

Comment: no this code i have written on my own, but i got my mistake , in second loop it should me j=i+1;

Comment: What happens when you swap the compare expression? I.e., `a[i] < a[j]`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your sorting runs two complete loops, comparing `a`s for all pairs of `i` and `j`, including ones where `i` is *greater* than `j` (at which point you shouldn't be swapping the items). In order for *selection sort* <sup>*</sup> to work, it needs to pick its swap candidates only from the unsorted portion of the array.

Here is how to fix your implementation:

```
for(i=0;i<10-1;i++) // You do not need to touch the last element, so end at 10-1
{    
    for (j=i+1;j<10;j++) // Make it j = i+1
    {   
       if(a[i] > a[j]) // >, not >= : no need to swap when two items are equal
       { 
          temp=a[i];
          a[i]=a[j];
          a[j]=temp;
       }
    }
}
```

<sup>*</sup> [*Selection Sort*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) is the fancy name of the sorting algorithm that you are implementing.

Comment: hey..i got my mistake...

Answer (score 3):

> Can you please tell me why I am always getting array `a[i]` in descending order only?

Because you implemented logic (comparisons) for descending order. Change

```
if(a[i]>=a[j])
```

to

```
if(a[i] < a[j])
```

See the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int a[10] = {3,15,9,4,15,65,0,2,1,1};
int temp; 
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
          for (int j=0;j<10;j++)
          {
             if(a[j] > a[i])
             {
                temp=a[i];
                a[i]=a[j];
                a[j]=temp;
             }
          }
     }

     for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
}
```

Here is the working code with output: http://ideone.com/DijpJD.

Steps of sorting process: Only those steps are shown where the changes has taken place.

```
Pass 1: 15   3   9   4  15  65   0   2   1   1  
        65   3   9   4  15  15   0   2   1   1      

Pass 2:  3  65   9   4  15  15   0   2   1   1  

Pass 3:  3   9  65   4  15  15   0   2   1   1  

Pass 4:  3   4  65   9  15  15   0   2   1   1  
         3   4   9  65  15  15   0   2   1   1  

Pass 5:  3   4   9  15  65  15   0   2   1   1  

Pass 6:  3   4   9  15  15  65   0   2   1   1      

Pass 7:  0   4   9  15  15  65   3   2   1   1  
         0   3   9  15  15  65   4   2   1   1  
         0   3   4  15  15  65   9   2   1   1  
         0   3   4   9  15  65  15   2   1   1  
         0   3   4   9  15  15  65   2   1   1 

Pass 8:  0   2   4   9  15  15  65   3   1   1  
         0   2   3   9  15  15  65   4   1   1  
         0   2   3   4  15  15  65   9   1   1  
         0   2   3   4   9  15  65  15   1   1  
         0   2   3   4   9  15  15  65   1   1  

Pass 9:  0   1   3   4   9  15  15  65   2   1  
         0   1   2   4   9  15  15  65   3   1  
         0   1   2   3   9  15  15  65   4   1  
         0   1   2   3   4  15  15  65   9   1  
         0   1   2   3   4   9  15  65  15   1  
         0   1   2   3   4   9  15  15  65   1  

Pass 10: 0   1   1   3   4   9  15  15  65   2  
         0   1   1   2   4   9  15  15  65   3  
         0   1   1   2   3   9  15  15  65   4  
         0   1   1   2   3   4  15  15  65   9  
         0   1   1   2   3   4   9  15  65  15  
         0   1   1   2   3   4   9  15  15  65
```

Comment: can u explain me my logic ? means some 2 3 iterations?

Comment: Actually, this is wrong. Its the loops that are the problem.

Comment: @Roddy; I don't know why people just star downvote without thinking over the logic. I posted the full code with the correction I told about. Now could you and all the downvoters explain me that what is wrong with this code?

Comment: @Priyanka It is intresting to understand why Haccks answer is correct!! hind is after swapping `a[i]`  will be greater then `a[j]`. And you are arranging `a[i]`  for all `i=0` to `i=9`.

Comment: @Roddy This is correct answer  I added a short explanation in comment

Comment: @girish , yes, thats what was my mistake.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan; Sometimes people just start downvoting because the do not understand the logic of the program :). But I do not think this is the case here because this code is too elementary. There might be some other reasons :)

Comment: @Priyanka Yes I am trying to explain you the what happens in your *old* code.

Comment: +1 It is actually very instructive to understand why this algorithm sorts the array in the opposite order. It turns out that the portion of the loop where `i` and `j` are "inverted" (i.e. where `j` is less than `i`) simply reverses the sorted portion of the array.

Comment: @Roddy; Now see the steps of sorting.

Comment: @haccks - undownvoted ;-) But unless I'm wrong, this is not any recognized sorting algorithm, and it involves twice as many compares as (extremely bad!) simple selection sort.

Comment: @Roddy; I often use sorting algos but I don't know all of them by name. I just answered the question. :)